# What's the best way to write a script to add windows 10 notifications natively, (i.e. without BurntToast)

Tags: vbscript, scripting, notifications, windows-10

I need to be able to display a notification on Windows 10. On a Mac I'd just execute a quick AppleScript:

```
osascript -e 'display notification "That’s all folks" with title "So long..." subtitle "...and thanks for all the fish." sound name "Frog"'
```

I can't find a Windows equivalent, and so I guess I'll have to write something. The only items I have come across all reference installing BurntToast. This is a no-no for the client. I don't mind if I have to write a simple VBS or something that I can call/invoke with parameters, just title and a short message would do. Any ideas?

Comment: Something like [`MsgBox`](https://ss64.com/vb/msgbox.html)?

Comment: If spawning a PowerShell process from VBScript is an option, then invoke something like this: `powershell.exe -NoLogo -NonInteractive -WindowStyle Hidden -Command .{ [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms'); [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing'); $notify = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon; $notify.Icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information; $notify.Visible = $true; $notify.ShowBalloonTip(5000, 'Information', 'Hello World!', [System.Windows.Forms.TooltipIcon]::None) }`